# Model Serving status is stopped in Databricks

Tags: databricks, mflow

After clicking Enable Serving button in Databricks, the Serving tab appeared with Status shown as Pending. After a few minutes, Status changed to Stoped. Does anyone have an idea for how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't have access to create a cluster within that workspace which you are running . You can check in model events tab exact error . Please connect with admin to get cluster creation access .[image: link]

Comment: Is there anyway to use existing cluster instead of creating new one ?